# What are the differences between BackgroundServices and SingletonServices?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a service which should begin when the server starts, and continue running for the entirety of the server lifetime. I would like to be able to manage the service (querying, modifying runtime options, etc) with a web frontend. While researching the best way to accomplish this, I came across two options: a scoped service with a singleton lifetime, and a backgroundservice/IHostedService. What are the differences between the two options, and when should one be used over the other?

Answer (score 20):

Neither of those is actually a thing. The closest is the concept of a singleton and hosted services. A hosted service is a class that implements `IHostedService` and pretty much fits the bill of what you're looking for in that it will start at app startup and stop at app shutdown. ASP.NET Core 3.0 added a `BackgroundService` class, which is just an implementation of `IHostedService` with a lot of the cruft of defining what happens as start/stop/etc. covered. In practice, it usually makes more sense to inherit from `BackgroundService`, but you can also just implement `IHostedService` directly yourself.

"Singleton" is just a lifetime. All hosted services are registered with a singleton lifetime, but just because something is a singleton, doesn't mean it does anything special. You could, for example, register some random class as a singleton, and whenever it is injected, you'll always get the same instance. However, it will not do anything at startup or shutdown on its own.

Long and short, there are no differing options here. You're looking for a hosted service. That said, it only solves part of what you're looking for, in that it will "run" while the app is running. However, you can't really connect to it, or interact with it directly. It's not like a Web Api or something; it isn't exposed for HTTP requests, for example.

To "manage" it, you would have to expose some sort of API that would then interact with the service through code. For example, the docs provide an example of a queued background service that processes things added to the queue. However, to queue something, you would need to do something like create an API endpoint, inject the queue, and then use code to add a new item to the queue. Then, the actual hosted service would eventually pop that task from the queue and work on it.

Comment: By singletonservice, I was referring to a service added using the AddSingleton method. I apologize for the confusion if that wasn't clear. Am I correct in my understanding that a hostedservice does not support the dependency injection framework that scoped services use?

Comment: No, it does. You add it via AddHostedService, and then you can inject services into it like any other registered service

Comment: What about the reverse, can I inject a hosted service into a controller?

Comment: @cubesnyc Instead of trying to inject a hosted service into a controller. You can abstract out the logic you want to reuse into a separate class. Then you can use the same class or functionality from controller and the hosted service by injecting it into both. Beware that HostedServices can only directly inject singleton dependencies only.